# Get custom option attributes in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to pass a custom attribute to my option field  named "data-id":

```
<option data-id={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
```

In my onChange function I know how to get the value, I'd do it like : `console.log(e.target.value)`

But how can you get a custom attribute like 'data-id'. Could you just do 'e.target.data-id' ? That didn't seem to work in my case. Is there a correct way of doing this (if it's even possible)

Comment: `e.target["data-id"]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object property with invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056075/how-to-access-object-property-with-invalid-characters)

Comment: Or the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/3001761. Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/33760520/3001761 specifically for HTML `data-` props.

Comment: May I ask you why you use data attributes in this case? Most of the time that shouldn't even be necessary. If the reason is that you want to identify which `id` was chosen then there are better ways to solve that in react.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dataset` property of the element. Have a look at this example:

```js
const testDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div');

testDiv.addEventListener('click', e => {
  testDiv.innerText = e.target.dataset.id
})
```

```css
.my-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div" data-id="abc"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [access the values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access) of data attributes through the `dataset` property:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id)
}
```