# API REST NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api

I am making an API REST with axios to get the data. This data is recieved correctly but when I access to the object it gaves me an error since the object is @graph, an mabe is because it has an special character. ¿How can i access to @graph?

[Object in the API i am trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF62g.png)

[Code I have implement and error to access @graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgyKY.png)

If someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object property with invalid characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056075/how-to-access-object-property-with-invalid-characters)

Comment: Or e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953704/3001761, probably quite a few others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let test = {
  "@graph": "test value"
};
console.log(test["@graph"]);
```

try with

```
console.log(url.data["@graph"])
```

cheers